# Why does merging branches sum total commits?

Tags: git, github

If Branch A has 5 commits and Branch B has 7, when I merge B into A, A now has 12 commits.

Is that the expected result? I wouldve thought a merge would be considered a single commit?

Comment: When two people get married, you don't wind up with three.

Comment: Did you push code to Git before merging?

Comment: @Said Yes. Both branches were fully pushed. B was a feature branch. Now I want to merge to A and the number of commits showing is now the total between the two.

Comment: The merge commit is considered a single commit (I’d expect 13 commits now, unless you’re not counting merge commits or one of the 5 and 7 is actually the same commit), but it brings all of the histories it merges together. So yes, the expectation is for there to be more than 8 commits making up the history of A, and if you graph them they look like… well, find something that graphs them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say "branch A has five commits", you're probably not counting all the commits that branch A contains.  The same applies to your seven commits in branch B.  To really understand this, it's important to realize that in Git, branches—or more precisely, branch *names*—don't actually have any meaning.  It's only the *commits* that matter.

To see how this works, let's start with a really tiny repository with just three commits in it.  The three commits have big long ugly Git-hash-ID names, but let's just call them commits `A`, `B`, and `C`, as if commits had single uppercase letters as their real names.  (We'll run out pretty fast, which is one reason Git uses those big ugly hash IDs.)

The first big important secret of Git is that every commit stores its *previous* commit's hash ID inside it.  Whenever you have the hash ID of a commit in your hands, we say that you're *pointing to* that commit.  So our three commits go like this:

```
A <-B <-C
```

Commit `C` stores `B`'s hash ID, so `C` points back to `B`.  `B` stores `A`'s hash ID, so `B` points back to `A`.  `A` is of course the very first commit we ever made: it can't point any further back.  It's a special case—a *root* commit, of which there's always at least one if the repository isn't empty.  Usually there's exactly one root commit, with that one being the very first commit.

#### Branch names

The next big important secret is a simple follow-on to this first one, and that is that a branch *name* like `master` or `develop` simply points to *one commit*.  The one commit that our `master` points to, in this case, will be commit `C`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

I always get a bit lazy about drawing the internal arrows between commits, for various reasons.  One is that once we make a commit, nothing and no one—not even Git itself—can *change* the commit.  Commit `C` is frozen in time forever, always pointing back to `B`, which is frozen and points to `A`, and so on.  The internal arrows therefore invariably point *backwards*.  Git calls these the *parents* of the commit: the parent of `C` is `B`, and the parent of `B` is `A`.

The branch name pointers are different.  Unlike the frozen contents of each commit, a branch name pointer *can and does* change.

Let's `git checkout master`, which extracts commit `C` into our *work tree*, giving us files we can see and work on / with.  Then we'll make some changes, `git add` the updated files, and `git commit` to make a new commit that we'll call `D`.  Git will package up our new files<sup>1</sup> and make this new commit `D`, pointing back to the commit we had out—i.e., `C`—so that we now have:

```
A--B--C--D
```

and then as its final act, `git commit` writes `D`'s hash ID into the name `master`, so that `master` now points not to `C` but to `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

This is how branches grow as you add new commits: each new commit points back to the one that *was* the last one in the branch, and then Git updates the branch name so that the name now identifies the new tip.  Whenever Git looks for the history—for what happened over time—it works by starting at the *last* commit, the one pointed-to by the name, and working backwards, one commit at a time.

#### Making new branches

To make a new *branch*, what Git does is just add a new *name* pointing to some existing commit.  Let's make branch `branch-a` now, in our four-commit repository:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, branch-a (HEAD)
```

Besides adding the name `branch-a` pointing to `D`, I've attached the special name `HEAD`—in all capitals, though you can use `@` if you like a shorter name—to one of the two branch names.  That's how Git remembers the *current branch*.

Before we make any new commits, answer for yourself: how many commits are there in `master`, and how many are there in `branch-a`?  If you didn't answer "four" each time, why not?  If you ask Git, the answer is four: there are four commits, `D` then `C` then `B` then `A`, on *both* branches.

Let's add five commits to our new `branch-a` now, by changing stuff and using `git add` and `git commit` in the usual way.  Git will construct five new, unique, big ugly hash IDs, but we'll call the new commits `E-F-G-H-I` and draw them in:

```
           E--F--G--H--I   <-- branch-a (HEAD)
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

When we made `E`, Git made it with parent `D`, and then changed the *name* `branch-a` to point to `E`.  When we made `F`, its parent was `E`, and Git updated `branch-a` to point to `F`.  We repeated this five times and we have five commits on `branch-a` that *aren't* on master, plus the four commits that are on *both branches*.  So `branch-a` has not five but rather *nine* commits.  It's just that five of them are *only* on `branch-a`.

Now let's make `branch-b`, by first switching back to `master` and then creating the new name `branch-b`, pointing to commit `D`:

```
           E--F--G--H--I   <-- branch-a
          /
A--B--C--D   <-- master, branch-b (HEAD)
```

Note that nothing else inside the repository itself has changed here.  Our *work-tree* (and index) have changed—they've gone back to commit `D`—and we've added a new name `branch-b` that, like `master`, identifies commit `D`, but the commits are all undisturbed.

Now let's add seven commits that are unique to `branch-b`:

```
           E--F--G--H--I   <-- branch-a
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           J--K--L--M--N--O--P   <-- branch-b (HEAD)
```

There are actually 11 commits on `branch-b`, but four of them are shared (with `master`, which I've stopped drawing out of laziness, and with `branch-a`).

#### Merging

Now you want to merge `branch-b` into `branch-a`.  So the commands you run will be:

```
git checkout branch-a
git merge branch-b
```

The first step chooses commit `I` as the current commit and `branch-a` as the name to which `HEAD` is to be attached.  It copies the contents of commit `I` to the work-tree (and index / staging-area).  There are no changes to the graph itself, but now `HEAD` indicates `branch-a` and hence commit `I`:

```
           E---F----G---H----I   <-- branch-a (HEAD)
          /
A--B--C--D
          \
           J--K--L--M--N--O--P   <-- branch-b
```

(I've also stretched out the top line a bit because of something I intend to draw in a moment.  The position of the commits in the graph is stretchy because Git doesn't care about the actual *time* of the commit, only about the shape of the commits and their connecting arcs, and you can bend and twist the graph however you like, as long as you don't break any of the connections, or make up new ones that aren't there.)

The `git merge` command then does something a little tricky.  First, it finds the *merge base* between the current commit `I` and the other commit `P`.  The merge base is, roughly speaking, the point where the two branches diverged.  In this case that's super-obvious from the graph: it's commit `D`.

Git now figures out what "we" changed on `branch-a` by doing:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-I>   # what we changed
```

It gets a second diff to find out what *they* changed on `branch-b`:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-D> <hash-of-P>   # what they changed
```

Git then combines the two sets of changes, applying the combined changes to whatever is in the snapshot in commit `D`.

This "make two diffs, combine them, and apply them to the merge base" process is the action form of merging.  I like to refer to this as the verb *to merge*, i.e., to combine changes.  Because commits are snapshots, not change-sets, Git has to do the two diffs.  In order to have a sensible starting point, Git has to find the merge base.  That's why we have all this work that happens as part of the verb *to merge* when we merge commits `I` and `P`.

#### Merge commits

Now that Git has done all this to-merge work, Git will make a *merge commit*.  Well, it will *often* or *usually* make one—we'll see the exceptions in a moment.  Note that this uses the word *merge* as an adjective, though, modifying the word *commit*.  We can also refer to this new merge commit as *a merge*, using the word *merge* as a noun.  I like to refer to this as merge-as-a-noun or merge-as-an-adjective, to distinguish it from the *process*, the *to merge* verb.  For the `git merge` command, we're doing the process first, then making the merge commit at the end.  But let's draw it:

```
           E---F----G---H----I
          /                   \
A--B--C--D                     Q   <-- branch-a (HEAD)
          \                   /
           J--K--L--M--N--O--P   <-- branch-b
```

This new commit, merge commit `Q`, is special in precisely one way: it has *two* parents instead of one.  It points back first to commit `I`, to say *commit `I` was at the tip of `branch-a` a moment ago and is a parent of commit `Q`*, but then it *also* points back to commit `P`, to say *commit `P` is also a parent of commit `Q`*.

If we now ask Git how many—and which—commits are on `branch-a`, Git starts at `Q`, then works backwards through *both* `I` *and* `P`, eventually arriving at `D` (to which `master` still points), and then all the way back to `A`.  So the number of commits is now 17: `A` through `D` plus `E` through `I` plus `J` through `P` plus `Q`.  If we ask how many commits are on `branch-a` that *aren't* on `master`, we get 13: five for `E` through `I`, seven for `J` through `P`, and one for `Q`.

#### There are lots of ways to draw this

Here's another way to draw what happened:

```
...--D--E--F--G--H--I------Q   <-- branch-a (HEAD)
      \                   /
       J--K--L--M--N--O--P   <-- branch-b
```

The *number of **reachable** commits* remains the same, though: Git starts at `Q`, moves back to both `I` and `P`, moves back to both `H` and `O`, and so on until reaching `D` when it moves back to whatever comes before shared commit `D`.

If you have `git log` draw the graph, using `git log --graph` or `git log --graph --oneline`, Git will draw it vertically, with commit `Q` at the top and the branching structure represented as individual lines:

```
* hashofQ (HEAD -> branch-a) Merge ..
|\
| * hashofP commit message for P
* | hashofI commit message for I
...
```

or similar—the exact position of each `*` and line depends on additional sorting options you may pass to `git log` such as `--author-date-order`, though `--graph` always enforces at least the `--topo-order` option.  Graphical viewers such as `gitk`, and various GUIs, may mimic `git log --graph --oneline` but make it all prettier (though as always, beauty is in the eye of the beholder).

#### Squash merge: `git merge` doesn't always merge

The `git merge` command can do more than build *a merge* (noun) using the *to merge* (verb) process.  [arkus mentioned `git merge --squash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56204067/1256452), which does the *to merge* part of the process, but then simply stops, without making a commit and without recording the fact that the next commit should be a merge.  In this particular case, we'd then run `git commit` ourselves to make commit `Q`.  New commit `Q` would be an *ordinary commit*, not a merge commit, and we might draw it in like this:

```
...--D--E--F--G--H--I--Q   <-- branch-a (HEAD)
      \
       J--K--L--M--N--O--P   <-- branch-b
```

Because there is no connection between `Q` and `P`, someone coming in later—including yourself, or Git—and looking at this graph may have no idea that commit `Q` is the result of a merge.  The seven commits that are exclusive to `branch-b` are still exclusive to `branch-b`.  In general, if you have done this, you *should* immediately *remove* the name `branch-b` from this repository *and* from *every clone of this repository*, so as to utterly forget that commits `J-K-L-M-N-O-P` ever existed.

This is sometimes, but not always, a viable, useful, and good work-flow.  It's particularly useful when the individual commits on `branch-b` have never been seen anywhere else, so that you *know* nobody else has them, *and* you only made them as temporary commits with the intent to replace them all with a single "add the feature" commit, i.e., commit `Q`, at the end.  After doing the squash merge, you force Git to delete your `branch-b` name and you forget that you ever did any of the individual commits.  You have one final good commit and you pretend to the world that you knew how to make that commit all at once.

Sometimes, though, even if you're introducing a feature, it's good to keep it as a series of separate commits.  In particular, what if you've introduced a bug too?  In that case, if you shrink your feature down to a series of simple but clear commits—let's say three of them—and then you merge them with a real merge, you get a graph like this:

```
...--D--E--F--G--H--I--Q   <-- branch-a (HEAD)
      \               /
       R-------S-----T   <-- branch-b
```

If it now turns out that you *have* introduced a bug, it's probably possible to check out commits `R` and `S` and `T` and see *which of those commits introduced the bug*.  Then you can compare `R` vs `D`, `S` vs `R`, or `T` vs `S`, to help you find out how the bug got in, and figure out what to do to fix it.

**What this boils down to is that squash merges aren't bad, they're just a tool.  Use your tools to do things in a way that will make life easier for yourself in the future.**  If that means squashing, go ahead and squash.  If not, don't.

#### Fast-forward: `git merge` doesn't always merge

We should also cover *fast-forward* operations.  Consider a situation in which you make a branch:

```
...--C--D   <-- master, feature (HEAD)
```

You then make some commits *on* that branch:

```
...--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E--F--G--H   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Everything seems great and you'd like to introduce the feature now, keeping all four of these commits intact.  If you now run:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

Git will say something about *fast-forward*, and you will be left with this graph:

```
...--C--D--E--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), feature
```

The name `feature` has not moved—it still points to commit `H`—but the name `master` *has* moved, and now also points to commit `H`.  There's no new merge commit!

What Git did here is that it did the merge-base finding just as it would for a real merge, and found that the best common commit between `master` and `feature` was commit `D`.  The name `master` pointed to commit `D`, though, so if Git were to do the usual *to merge* verb, it would run:

```
git diff --find-renames *hash-of-D* *hash-of-D*   # what we changed
```

and the answer would, of course, be *we changed nothing!*  Then Git would need to diff `D` vs `H` to find out what they changed, which of course would be whatever they changed.  Git would apply those changes to `D` and get ... commit `H`, again.

If Git made a real merge out of this, it would look like:

```
...--C--D------------I   <-- master (HEAD)
         \          /
          E--F--G--H   <-- feature
```

The snapshot for commit `I` would match that for commit `H`.

You can *force* Git to make this merge commit:

```
git checkout master; git merge --no-ff feature
```

That way you get the same kind of true merge you would have gotten had `master` had some commit after `D`.  You *can* do this if you want to emphasize to a future viewer—who may well be yourself in a year or two—that commits `E-F-G-H` were made as a group, and together they implement some feature.  Or you may not care: you, and future-you a year from now, may prefer to just see commits `E-F-G-H` as a logical extension of `master`, without any need to remember that these four were done specifically for some particular feature.

Again, this really boils down to the fact that **fast-forward merge vs real merge is a tool, which you can use to communicate information to future users of this repository.  Use your tools to arrange things to make the life of future-you easier.**

f you think you'll prefer to see the merge in a `git log --graph` or graphical viewer, force the non-fast-forward merge with `git merge --no-ff`.  If you think you'll prefer *not* to see the merge, you can even use `git merge --ff-only` to make sure that Git will just *fail* if a true merge is required (after which you will need to do something different, and that's beyond the scope of this already-too-long answer).

Comment: What if you have hundreds of feature branches over time, and each have hundreds of commits; wont master (final merge) end up having hundreds if not thousands of commits? Should we allow users to view all those commits on master and see all the "sausage" making?

Comment: @pstatix: yes, it will. Take a look at, e.g., the Git repository for Git, or for Linux. This sort of thing is why `git log` (and other viewers) do or should have a lot of mechanisms by which they can deliberately *hide* commits. A typical case with `git log` is, e.g., `git log origin/master..master`, which says: *show all commits reachable from `master`, excluding all commits reachable from `origin/master`.*

Comment: And its perfectly acceptable to show all that history which may be entire branches merging?

Comment: Unless you tell it otherwise, yes. Consider `git log --first-parent`, which tells Git: *every time you reach a merge, instead of following all legs, follow only the first-parent leg of the merge.*

Comment: I suppose what I am getting at is that to the public, I don't want them to see the 45 commits it took to make Feature A on Branch A after I deploy (merge) Branch A onto Master. Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: For that case, either rewrite the feature-A commits into a smaller set (using, e.g., `git rebase -i`) and merge that, or rewrite it down to a single commit and merge or append that, which is easiest with `git merge --squash` followed by simply *deleting* the branch name and with it, access to those commits.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the history of the branches... it could be between 7 revisions (a fast-forward) and 13 revisions (merging 2 totally unrelated stories). It all depends on the stories and how many diverging revisions you are talking about (or if you are forcing a `--no-ff`). One possible way to get 12 revisions is to have a single common ancestor between both branches, so you have the common ancestor, 4 revisions on one branch and 6 on the other (after the common ancestor) plus the merge revision: 1 + 4 + 6 + 1 = 12. But as I said, it all depends on the history. 8 could be achieved by having all 5 revisions of one branch be the first 5 revisions of the other branch and then do merge --no-ff. That will create a merge commit for what would have been a ff. Result: 8 revisions. With 4 common ancestors and merging you get 9 revisions... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge the branch with 1 commit, you could use `--squash` option fo `git merge`.

What it does is it creates one commit from the branch passed in `git merge --squash <branch>`, which you can commit.

Default `git merge branch`:

[image]

`git merge --squash branch`:

[image]